# What is the meaning of ground truth?

Tags: american-english, british-english

I am reading the paper : http://mi-lab.org/files/2014/10/FlexSense_web.pdf .
I have problems understanding use of *ground truth* the following :

> Main Pipeline
>   Reconstructing the full 3D surface shape from a sparse set of
>   sensor measurements is clearly a challenging task. Each sensor
>   reading from our foil is an amplified voltage measurement,
>   and somehow we need to map these combined values to a
>   real-world reconstruction of the surface. In this section we
>   present two data-driven algorithms that tackle this problem.
>   Both of our methods are first trained using pairs of sensor
>   measurements and **ground truth** 3D shape measurements of
>   the foil. This pre-processing training phase is what enables
>   our algorithms to infer the shape of the foil from the sparse
>   sensor data at runtime.
>   To collect ground truth measurements of the shape of the foil
>   together with corresponding sensor measurements, we follow
>   the approach illustrated in Figure 5. We print an array of
>   markers on a sheet of paper covering our sensor foil. Then
>   we use a custom-built multi-camera rig (described later) to
>   track the 3D position of the markers with high accuracy. We
>   leverage multiple cameras in order to track as many markers
>   as possible despite occlusions due to the deforming foil and
>   interacting hands.

What exactly does *ground truth* mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_truth)

> Ground truth is a term used in various fields to refer to information provided by direct observation as opposed to information provided by inference.

Comment: Yes. It'll set you free.